# How many points $\xi\in\mathbb Z^n$ are there satisfying $p\leq|\xi|< p+1$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p\in\mathbb N$. How many points $\xi\in\mathbb Z^n$ are there satisfying $p\leq|\xi|< p+1$? Here $|\xi|$ indicates the usual Euclidian norm.

I am trying to decide convergence in [How to show the series $\displaystyle\sum_{\xi\in\mathbb Z^n}\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}}$ converges if and only if $s>n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669891/how-to-show-the-series-displaystyle-sum-xi-in-mathbb-zn-frac11-xi2)

Comment: If $r_n(k)$ is the sum-of-$n$-squares function (which counts the number of ways $k$ can be written as $n$ squares), what you have is $\sum_{k=p^2}^{(p+1)^2-1}r_n(k)$.

Comment: No exact count possible. Estimate given in answer.

Answer (score 2):

The count you are asking about is approximately a constant times $p^{n-1}.$ The constant depends on $n.$

Let $\omega_n$ denote the $n$-volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n.$ So $\omega_2 = \pi$ and $\omega_3 = 4 \pi/3.$ The shorthand is $\omega_n = \pi^{n/2} / (n/2)!$ officially 
$$  \omega_n = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{n}{2} \right)}.   $$
The volume of the ball of radius $R$ is 
$$ \omega_n \; R^n.  $$
The $n-1$-surface area of the sphere of radius $R$ is
$$ n \; \omega_n \; R^{n-1}.  $$

The $n$-volume of the spherical shell of real points with norm from $p$ to $p+1$ is about
$$ n \; \omega_n \; p^{n-1}.  $$
This is the best approximation you are likely to find for the number of integer points in your set.

For $n=2,$ I did a computer run, $p$ then the count then the count divided by $p,$ showing an approximation for $2 \pi \approx 6.283.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
   0       1                      inf
   1       8                        8
   2      16                        8
   3      20                  6.66667
   4      24                        6
   5      40                        8
   6      36                        6
   7      48                  6.85714
   8      56                        7
   9      56                  6.22222
  10      68                      6.8
  11      64                  5.81818
  12      80                  6.66667
  13      92                  7.07692
  14      88                  6.28571
  15      96                      6.4
  16      96                        6
  17     116                  6.82353
  18     120                  6.66667
  19     120                  6.31579
  20     124                      6.2
  21     144                  6.85714
  22     136                  6.18182
  23     140                  6.08696
  24     152                  6.33333
  25     168                     6.72
  26     176                  6.76923
  27     164                  6.07407
  28     168                        6
  29     192                  6.62069
  30     188                  6.26667
  31     208                  6.70968
  32     200                     6.25
  33     208                  6.30303
  34     228                  6.70588
  35     208                  5.94286
  36     232                  6.44444
  37     228                  6.16216
  38     256                  6.73684
  39     248                  6.35897
  40     236                      5.9
  41     272                  6.63415
  42     264                  6.28571
  43     288                  6.69767
  44     276                  6.27273
  45     272                  6.04444
  46     296                  6.43478
  47     292                  6.21277
  48     312                      6.5
  49     304                  6.20408
  50     336                     6.72
  51     324                  6.35294
  52     312                        6
  53     344                  6.49057
  54     324                        6
  55     376                  6.83636
  56     344                  6.14286
  57     360                  6.31579
  58     364                  6.27586
  59     368                  6.23729
  60     392                  6.53333
  61     388                  6.36066
  62     392                  6.32258
  63     400                  6.34921
  64     388                   6.0625
  65     432                  6.64615
  66     400                  6.06061
  67     424                  6.32836
  68     452                  6.64706
  69     416                  6.02899
  70     448                      6.4
  71     428                  6.02817
  72     480                  6.66667
  73     464                  6.35616
  74     464                  6.27027
  75     476                  6.34667
  76     480                  6.31579
  77     496                  6.44156
  78     476                  6.10256
  79     496                  6.27848
  80     520                      6.5
  81     500                  6.17284
  82     536                  6.53659
  83     504                  6.07229
  84     536                  6.38095
  85     548                  6.44706
  86     544                  6.32558
  87     552                  6.34483
  88     524                  5.95455
  89     600                  6.74157
  90     552                  6.13333
  91     576                  6.32967
  92     580                  6.30435
  93     584                  6.27957
  94     608                  6.46809
  95     580                  6.10526
  96     600                     6.25
  97     632                  6.51546
  98     608                  6.20408
  99     644                  6.50505
 100     608                     6.08
 101     664                  6.57426
 102     644                  6.31373
 103     624                  6.05825
 104     672                  6.46154
 105     644                  6.13333
 106     696                  6.56604
 107     672                  6.28037
 108     664                  6.14815
 109     684                  6.27523
 110     688                  6.25455
 111     720                  6.48649
 112     700                     6.25
 113     712                  6.30088
 114     744                  6.52632
 115     720                  6.26087
 116     716                  6.17241
 117     736                   6.2906
 118     752                  6.37288
 119     756                  6.35294
 120     752                  6.26667
 121     736                  6.08264
 122     772                  6.32787
 123     824                  6.69919
 124     752                  6.06452
 125     808                    6.464
 126     756                        6
 127     816                   6.4252
 128     824                   6.4375
 129     788                  6.10853
 130     840                  6.46154
 131     808                  6.16794
 132     864                  6.54545
 133     844                  6.34586
 134     800                  5.97015
 135     880                  6.51852
 136     852                  6.26471
 137     872                  6.36496
 138     864                  6.26087
 139     852                   6.1295
 140     912                  6.51429
 141     872                   6.1844
 142     896                  6.30986
 143     900                  6.29371
 144     912                  6.33333
 145     936                  6.45517
 146     908                  6.21918
 147     912                  6.20408
 148     952                  6.43243
 149     944                  6.33557
 150     948                     6.32
 151     920                  6.09272
 152     976                  6.42105
 153     948                  6.19608
 154    1000                  6.49351
 155     960                  6.19355
 156     976                  6.25641
 157    1020                  6.49682
 158     960                  6.07595
 159    1000                  6.28931
 160    1004                    6.275
 161    1056                  6.55901
 162    1024                  6.32099
 163     996                  6.11043
 164    1040                  6.34146
 165    1032                  6.25455
 166    1080                  6.50602
 167    1028                  6.15569
 168    1024                  6.09524
 169    1096                  6.48521
 170    1076                  6.32941
 171    1080                  6.31579
 172    1064                  6.18605
 173    1112                  6.42775
 174    1108                  6.36782
 175    1080                  6.17143
 176    1112                  6.31818
 177    1084                  6.12429
 178    1152                  6.47191
 179    1136                  6.34637
 180    1108                  6.15556
 181    1144                  6.32044
 182    1168                  6.41758
 183    1176                  6.42623
 184    1116                  6.06522
 185    1168                  6.31351
 186    1200                  6.45161
 187    1172                  6.26738
 188    1184                  6.29787
 189    1168                  6.17989
 190    1192                  6.27368
 191    1228                  6.42932
 192    1176                    6.125
 193    1248                  6.46632
 194    1196                  6.16495
 195    1248                      6.4
 196    1248                  6.36735
 197    1224                   6.2132
 198    1260                  6.36364
 199    1232                  6.19095
 200    1296                     6.48
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Then I did a computer run for $n=3$ and count / $p^2,$ showing an approximation for $4 \pi \approx 12.566$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
   p    count             count / p^2
   0       1                      inf
   1      26                       26
   2      66                     16.5
   3     158                  17.5556
   4     234                   14.625
   5     410                     16.4
   6     470                  13.0556
   7     738                  15.0612
   8     866                  13.5312
   9    1170                  14.4444
  10    1358                    13.58
  11    1626                   13.438
  12    1970                  13.6806
  13    2366                       14
  14    2538                   12.949
  15    3074                  13.6622
  16    3306                  12.9141
  17    3926                  13.5848
  18    4242                  13.0926
  19    4826                  13.3684
  20    5270                   13.175
  21    5754                  13.0476
  22    6338                   13.095
  23    7014                   13.259
  24    7370                  12.7951
  25    8330                   13.328
  26    8754                  12.9497
  27    9710                  13.3196
  28    9858                   12.574
  29   11162                  13.2723
  30   11358                    12.62
  31   12770                  13.2882
  32   13106                  12.7988
  33   14250                  13.0854
  34   14894                  12.8841
  35   15858                  12.9453
  36   16706                  12.8904
  37   17550                  12.8196
  38   18626                  12.8989
  39   19682                  12.9402
  40   20382                  12.7387
  41   21794                  12.9649
  42   22602                  12.8129
  43   24050                   13.007
  44   24846                  12.8337
  45   26042                  12.8602
  46   26810                  12.6701
  47   28494                   12.899
  48   29426                  12.7717
  49   30978                  12.9021
  50   31826                  12.7304
  51   33758                  12.9789
  52   34386                  12.7167
  53   36314                  12.9277
  54   36678                  12.5782
  55   39146                  12.9408
  56   39882                  12.7175
  57   41258                  12.6987
  58   43310                  12.8746
  59   44226                   12.705
  60   46370                  12.8806
  61   47334                  12.7208
  62   48770                  12.6873
  63   51498                  12.9751
  64   51350                  12.5366
  65   54818                  12.9747
  66   54810                  12.5826
  67   57434                  12.7944
  68   59190                  12.8006
  69   60602                  12.7288
  70   62202                  12.6943
  71   64046                   12.705
  72   65954                  12.7226
  73   68898                  12.9289
  74   69098                  12.6183
  75   72222                  12.8395
  76   73082                  12.6527
  77   75434                  12.7229
  78   77238                  12.6953
  79   79322                  12.7098
  80   81090                  12.6703
  81   83630                  12.7465
  82   86250                  12.8272
  83   87362                  12.6814
  84   89258                  12.6499
  85   92454                  12.7964
  86   93818                   12.685
  87   96474                  12.7459
  88   97166                  12.5473
  89  101994                  12.8764
  90  102794                  12.6906
  91  104978                   12.677
  92  107574                  12.7096
  93  109826                  12.6981
  94  111954                  12.6702
  95  114830                  12.7235
  96  116210                  12.6096
  97  120066                  12.7608
  98  121898                  12.6924
  99  124470                  12.6997
 100  126458                  12.6458
 101  130266                  12.7699
 102  131414                  12.6311
 103  135122                  12.7365
 104  137010                  12.6673
 105  139886                  12.6881
 106  142194                  12.6552
 107  146042                  12.7559
 108  146634                  12.5715
 109  151598                  12.7597
 110  152042                  12.5655
 111  157506                  12.7835
 112  158582                  12.6421
 113  162258                  12.7072
 114  164882                  12.6871
 115  167898                  12.6955
 116  170246                  12.6521
 117  173858                  12.7006
 118  175578                  12.6097
 119  179246                  12.6577
 120  182682                  12.6862
 121  185690                  12.6829
 122  188174                  12.6427
 123  192666                  12.7349
 124  194498                  12.6495
 125  199002                  12.7361
 126  198566                  12.5073
 127  205074                  12.7146
 128  206954                  12.6315
 129  211502                  12.7097
 130  213738                  12.6472
 131  217394                  12.6679
 132  221154                  12.6925
 133  225110                   12.726
 134  225186                   12.541
 135  231146                  12.6829
 136  234566                   12.682
 137  237162                  12.6358
 138  241250                   12.668
 139  243870                   12.622
 140  248882                  12.6981
 141  251034                  12.6268
 142  254714                  12.6321
 143  259790                  12.7043
 144  261402                  12.6062
 145  267842                  12.7392
 146  268374                  12.5903
 147  274250                  12.6915
 148  276914                  12.6422
 149  281874                  12.6965
 150  282734                   12.566
 151  288762                  12.6644
 152  291098                  12.5995
 153  298278                   12.742
 154  299282                  12.6194
 155  303650                  12.6389
 156  306906                  12.6112
 157  311774                  12.6485
 158  316242                  12.6679
 159  319682                  12.6451
 160  322350                  12.5918
 161  329354                  12.7061
 162  332114                  12.6549
 163  335406                   12.624
 164  340538                  12.6613
 165  344514                  12.6543
 166  347306                  12.6036
 167  353238                  12.6659
 168  355130                  12.5826
 169  362570                  12.6946
 170  365094                   12.633
 171  369986                   12.653
 172  373554                  12.6269
 173  378146                  12.6348
 174  382982                  12.6497
 175  387690                  12.6593
 176  390362                  12.6021
 177  394638                  12.5966
 178  400466                  12.6394
 179  406074                  12.6736
 180  409742                  12.6464
 181  412442                  12.5894
 182  419058                  12.6512
 183  425090                  12.6934
 184  426414                  12.5949
 185  433154                  12.6561
 186  436386                  12.6138
 187  444302                  12.7056
 188  443282                  12.5419
 189  452346                  12.6633
 190  453962                  12.5751
 191  463806                  12.7136
 192  462986                  12.5593
 193  472082                  12.6737
 194  474462                  12.6066
 195  481850                  12.6719
 196  485538                   12.639
 197  487514                  12.5619
 198  495966                  12.6509
 199  500546                  12.6397
 200  504746                  12.6187
   p    count             count / p^2
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: ? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @anon, I put in more. The OP wants to know estimates about convergence for a series in his previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $X_{n,p}$ the number of the integer points $\xi\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ satisfying $p\le|\xi|<p+1$.
Here is a very rough upper bound for $X_{n,p}$.

For every $\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ denote by $E_\xi$ the unit cube translated to $\xi$:
$$
E_\xi := \xi + [0,1)^n = [\xi_1,\xi_1+1)\times\cdots\times[\xi_n,\xi_n+1).
$$
If $\xi,\eta\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\xi\ne\eta$, then $E_\xi$ and $E_\eta$ are disjoint. If $A$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, then the number of elements of $A$ is equal to the $n$-volume of the union $\bigcup_{\xi\in A}E_\xi$.

The diameter of $E_\xi$ is equal to $\sqrt{n}$.
If $p>\sqrt{n}$ and $p\le|\xi|<p+1$, then $E_\xi$ is contained in the spherical shell $B(p+1+\sqrt{n})\setminus B(p-\sqrt{n})$.
Therefore $X_{n,p}$ is less than or equal to the $n$-volume of this shell:
$$
X_{n,p}
\le\omega_n((p+1+\sqrt{n})^n-(p-\sqrt{n})^n).
$$
In fact, the inequality is strict, but it is not important.
Apply the formula $a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a^j b^{n-1-j}$:
$$
X_{n,p}\le\omega_n (1+2\sqrt{n}) \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(p+1+\sqrt{n})^j(p-\sqrt{n})^{n-1-j}.
$$
Estimate $p-\sqrt{n}$ by $p+1+\sqrt{n}$:
$$
X_{n,p}\le n\omega_n (1+2\sqrt{n}) (p+1+\sqrt{n})^{n-1}.
$$
This is enough to conclude that the original serie converges for every $s>n$.